# Safely pass arguments to hive query

Tags: python, hadoop, sqlalchemy, hive

Is there a way to **safely** pass arguments to a hive query? I do not want to format query strings. With my MySQL database + SQLAlchemy I can pass the arguments to the database connection, and the engine does it for me. I would like to do something like I have below. But the `client.execute` function does not accept arguments. I'm running hive 0.10.0.

```
from datetime import date
from hive_service import ThriftHive
from hive_service.ttypes import HiveServerException
from thrift.transport import TSocket, TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol

transport = TSocket.TSocket(settings.HIVE_SERVER, settings.HIVE_PORT)
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
client = ThriftHive.Client(protocol)
transport.open()

q = """
    select *
    from tbl
    where dt = %(query_date)s
    limit 10
    """

params = {'query_date':date(2016,1,1)}
client.execute(q, params)
results = client.fetchAll()
```

Comment: I think you mean pass **arguments** to hive query.  But this is a very good question other then that technicality.

Comment: thanks for that, edited my question.